# Rails - Delayed job completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a web application based on ruby on rails, which uses [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) delayed job gem.

I have a function that triggers a delayed job which in turn triggers several other delayed jobs. Is there a way, nest case being an event that can indicate that all the jobs related to a parent have completed? Or do I just have to work on whatever data is available when I try to retrieve docuemnts ?

Example:

```
def create_vegetable
#..... creates some vegetable
end

def create_vegetable_asynchronously id
  Farm.delay(priority: 30, owner: User.where("authentication.auth_token" => token).first, class_name: "Farm", job_name:create "create_vegetable_asynchronously").create_vegetable(id)
end

def create_farm_asynchronously data
  data.each do |vegetable|
    create_vegetable_asynchronously vegetable.id
  end
end

handle_asynchronously :create_farm_asynchoronously
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe a little overkill, but you can explicitly organize your jobs hierarchically and employ before hook to pass on the parent job id to subtasks. 
something like:

```
class Job < Delayed::Job
  belongs_to :parent, class: 'Job' #also add db column for parent_id
end

class CreateVegetable 

   def initialize(id)
     @id = id
   end

   def perform
     Farm.create_vegetable(id)
   end

end


class CreateFarm 
   def initialize(vegetable_ids,owner_id)
     @vegetable_ids = vegetable_ids
     @owner_id = owner_id
   end

   def before(job)
     @job_id = job.id
   end

   def perform
     @vegetable_ids.each { |id| Job.enqueue CreateVegetable.new(id), priority: 30, owner_id = @owner_id, :parent_id = @job_id }
   end

end
```

Then when you launch create farm, somehow remember the job id.

```
def create_farm_asynchronously data
   owner_id = User.where("authentications.auth_token" => token).first.id
   @parent = Job.enqueue CreateFarm.new(data.map(&:id), owner_id)
end
```

then you can check sub-jobs by:

```
Job.where(parent_id: @parent.id)
```